# In shiny, is it possible to get the size of an ui element in the server?

Tags: r, shiny

I am building an app in shiny, that generates a custom svg file. When doing so, I would like to adapt the resolution to the element of the ui (in my case, a box from shinydashboard) it will be placed in.

Is there a way for my code in server.R to query the size (in pixels) of a box in the ui ?

I would imagine something like: `ui$mybox$height` and  `ui$mybox$width`

Comment: I found this line:

`if (width == 'auto')
      width <- shinysession$clientData[[paste(prefix, name, '_width', sep='')]];`
in:
https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/blob/master/R/shinywrappers.R#L110 ... not sure yet how to use this in an app, but it seems to be the right track

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found out that you can indeed access some information about the ui from the server.

To answer the question, you can get the width and height of an element created with `plotOutput("plot1")` using `session$clientData[["output_plot1_width"]]` and `session$clientData[["output_plot1_height"]]`.

To get an exhaustive list of what info is available in a given session, go in debug-mode in a reactive expression in `server.R` (for instance in `renderText()` and type `reactiveValuesToList(session$clientData)`.

Comment: thank you for that answer. Any idea how to get those values in the UI? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If someone looking to these question you can use r2d3 and just get the size of all the container you'd like using

```
var width=document.getElementById(id_container).offsetWidth;
var height= document.getElementById(id_container).offsetHeight
```

and make the construction of your svg element depends on.